# Line Cross then give signal once only and not repeat

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am looking for pine script coding with condition when pivot line here blue color of price 179.85 when any candle cross with green (close>open) then give signal, but only once.
If in case again same situation come then avoid repeating signal.

Thanks in advance...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Afgit.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the crossover function from pinescript (v5):

```
alreadycrossed = false
numberofalert = 0
numbermaxofalert = 1

if ta.crossover(close, pivotline)
    alreadycrossed := true

if alreadycrossed and numberofalert < numbermaxofalert
    alert("my alert")
    numberofalert := numberofalert + 1
```

This way, you will have an alert only the first time the price cross above your pivotline.
Be carefull, in this code, the pivotline must be a serie of float (cf the pinescript manual : [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta{dot}crossover](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dcrossover))

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion but not working, reason crossover situation repeats again and again signal appeared on chart. I want only once. That reason, Pivot value to be "na" after alert till get new Pivot or any other solution to get rid of repetitions.

Comment: @rr1050 okay but when should you receive the second signal?

Comment: when new pivotline is created and again cross with green candle.

Comment: @rt1050 I edit my code, now you will have only 1 alert...

Comment: @rr1050, if you find the answer usefull, please accept it .